# forever start command not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-14.04, forever

I am using following command to start forever command:

```
/usr/local/bin/forever start /var/www/html/test.js  | tee /tmp/forever-start.log
```

But it doesn't work. Not printing output in log file. 
In `test.js`, 
I have this code: `console.log('Server running...');`

Comment: run with node first to see if there any error in your script. "node /var/www/html/test.js"

Comment: ok @Darshan let me test

Comment: @Darshan using this command `nodejs /var/www/html/test.js` i can see the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forever will not output what you're printing with `console.log`.

You should use forever's `-o OUTFILE` option to specify a log file. Like so:

```
forever start -o /tmp/forever-start.log /var/www/html/test.js
```

Comment: where i have to write this? in this command : `/usr/local/bin/forever start /var/www/html/test.js  | tee /tmp/forever-start.log `

Comment: @PathikVejani See my edited answer. With `tee` you would only redirect the output of `forever` itself, which is usually nothing or just some status messages.

Comment: @PathikVejani After you run `forever start`, you can run `forever list` to show which processes you have running. In the case of this simple test file, `forever list` won't list anything, because the process exits immediately. However, you will see the output in the specified log file.

Comment: still nothing happens

Comment: then how can i check for listing?

Comment: log file is still empty.

Comment: What versions are you running? `node -v; forever --version`

Comment: nodejs verson: **v0.10.25** to check forever vesrion that command is not working